# What is the best path to learn intuitionistic logic?

Tags: logic

Is it preferred to look at intuitionistic logic as a special case of classical logic then branch from there since the two are largely similar aside from the results built on LEM, DNE and CP?

or, since intuitionistic logic is the "weaker" version, would it be safer to start with it?

my math background is that for engineering but pure logic wasn't a primary focus. What I know about pure logic is mostly due to self study (Kenneth Rosen's book on discrete mathematics was and still is a great introduction) but what my university curriculum was more interested in was enough to build and reduce logic circuits so, naturally, it wasn't interested in pure logic (they coincide but that's it).

edit: it would be better if suggested materials aren't the 'for X' type, as those are often tailored to suit the intended audience without going into the heart of the matter. this is just a personal opinion of mine but analogy-based approaches are flawed and incomplete.
still, if you think that a certain 'for X' material is doing okay on that front, please go for it.

edit #2: i came across [this book](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/logics/) and it seems to build from ground up in a friendly way to non-classical logics. any thoughts about it?

Comment: From my personal experience: Learn working with a proof assistant which has an underlying intuitionistic/constructive logic. It does not only help you in learning by catching all your mistakes, but It also becomes very fun to use once you get into it. Since you mentioned your background is engineering maybe this book could be a fit: http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/ but honestly I (as of yet) have not found the perfect book to recommend to beginners. (Here is some more https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/)

Comment: [van Dalen](https://www.cin.ufpe.br/~mlogica/livros/Logic%20and%20Structure%20-%20Van%20Dalen.pdf)'s textbook has a dedicated chapter.

Comment: More details into Anne Troelstra & Dirk van Dalen [Constructivism in mathematics : An Introduction (NorthHolland, 1988)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Constructivism_in_Mathematics_Vol_1/l4SXzQEACAAJ)

Comment: Relevant also [CTT](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory-intuitionistic/) for the computer approach to logic. See B.Nordström, Kent Petersson, and Jan M. Smith, [Programming in Martin-Löf’s type theory. An introduction (1990)](https://www.cse.chalmers.se/research/group/logic/book/book.pdf)

Comment: @Lereau any such proof assistant in mind?

Comment: @msaa Sure! The mentioned books are both about [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/) (here is a version you can [use online](https://jscoq.github.io/scratchpad.html) ). Another option is e.g. [Agda](https://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php).

Comment: I've had a look at the freely available first chapter of the book you linked. It seems like a good introduction and I especially like the approach of presenting a handful of logics.